# The expected value of product of random variables which have the same distribution but are not independent

Tags: pr.probability, lower-bounds, expectation

Given a positive integer $k$, is there a positive real number $c(k)$ such that  $\mathbb{E}\left(\prod_{i=1}^k X_i\right)\geq c(k)$ for any $k$-random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_k$ which all have the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$?  What's the optimal value of $c(k)$? It's known that $c(2)=\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\int_{[0,1]} \Pi_{i=1}^k X_i dx$? Do you perhaps mean the expectation of $ \Pi_{i=1}^k X_i$?

Comment: @JamesMartin Yes. The probability space is $[0,1]$, so the integral is the same as the expected value. The latter is a better notation for random variables.  I will edit the question.

Comment: you get a bound by taking logs & using Jensen

Comment: "It's known that c(2) = 1/6" << Can you link to a reference? Is there a name for this function c?

Comment: @Stef When $k=2$, it follows from rearrangement inequalities. View  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality for a discrete analogue.

Comment: when $k=2$, you may simply integrate the inequality $2X_1X_2\geqslant X_1(1-X_1)+X_2(1-X_2)+(X_1+X_2-1)$

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thanks. But the OP wrote "It is known that c(2) = 1/6", not "It is easy to prove c(2) = 1/6 using rearrangement inequalities", which suggests this problem has been discussed or studied somewhere before.

Comment: for $k=3$ the problem is addressed in the paper by Alexander Zimin and Nikita Gladkov , and the things which happen in this case do not suggest that the answer for general $k$ has any chances to be explicit https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.08554.pdf - but of course we may think on the reasonable bounds

Comment: @FedorPetrov Nice find! The asymptotic question would be the base of the exponent: Jensen gives a lower bound of $e^{-k}$, and taking $X_i$'s independent already gives an upper bound of $2^{-k}$. One can improve the upper bound by blowing up examples for fixed $k$ (such as $k=2$ or $k=3$), but I don't see how to improve (or match) the lower bound. Any ideas?

Comment: @mathworker21 not a find really, I was well aware of this work, listening the talks and discussing the stuff with the authors. It is amazing that if we fix two-dimensional uniform distributions of $(X_i,X_j), 1\leqslant i <j \leqslant 3$, then the optimal measure for $\int X_1X_2X_3$ leaves on the "surface" $X_1\oplus X_2\oplus X_3=1$, where $\oplus$ is a binary bit-sum (=XOR).

Comment: for large $k$ I would try the distribution on the hypersurface $X_1\ldots X_k=c^{-k}$ (cut by $0<X_i<1$), its marginals are not uniform, but possibly not that not uniform?

Comment: for improving a lower bound, we may try to find a pointwise estimate $x_1\ldots x_k\geqslant \sum_{i=1}^k f(x_i)$, $x_i\in [0,1]$, with maximal possible $\int f$. mike's argument corresponds to $f(x)=e^{-k}(1/k+(1+\log x))$.

Comment: @mathworker21: the following example shows that asymptotically the "truth" is near the lower bound given by Jensen.
Let  $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_k)$ be uniform on the $k-1$-dimensional simplex $\mathcal{S}_{k-1}:=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\in [0,1]^k\,\mid \sum_{i=1}^k x_i=1\}$, and let $X_i:=(1-Y_i)^{k-1}$.
Then each $X_i$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ and  $$d_k:=\mathbb{E}\prod_{i=1}^k X_i=\mathbb{E}\prod_{i=1}^k (1-Y_i)^{k-1}\leq \big((1-\frac{1}{k})^k\big)^{k-1}\approx e^{\tfrac{1}{2}-k} $$ 
since by the AGM-inequality $\prod_{i=1}^k (1-Y_i)\leq (1-\frac{1}{k})^k$.

Comment: @esg Sorry for the late response; thank you very much for your comment! Very nice. Don't know how you thought of it though...

Comment: @mathworker21: not much thought, really. I thought about constructing (highly dependent) uniform marginals using Dirichlet distributions (and was lucky at the first try).

Answer (score 7):

The answer to the first question is positive, and the lower bound is achieved, since the set of all probability measures on $[0,1]^k$ with uniform marginals is compact and since the integral of the bounded continuous function $(x_1,\ldots,x_k) \mapsto x_1 \cdots x_k$ on $[0,1]^k$ depends continuously of the probability measure.

Moreover, given such a probability measure $\pi$ on $[0,1]^k$, the integral of $x_1 \cdots x_k$ with regard to $\pi$ is strictly positive since $x_1 \cdots x_k>0$ for $\pi$-almost every $(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$.

Yet, finding the minimum is not obvious. For all $i<j$, the conditional distribution of $(X_i,X_j)$ given $X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\ldots,X_{j-1},X_{j+1},\ldots,X_k$ should be the decreasing coupling.

Comment: I feel like the argument in the first paragraph shows that $c(k)$ exists and is *nonnegative*; why is it strictly positive?

Comment: @Greg Martin I completed the answer to explain why.